# How can I start to use fromRunnable in RxJava?

Tags: android, rx-java

I am new to RxJava and I faced with the problem that I cannot use fromRunnable in "Async Operators" in order to use Runnable.

On gitHub it is said

> The following operators are part of the distinct rxjava-async module.

and in Gradle I have implemented this

```
dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'

    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:0.4.0'

    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava-async-util:0.21.0'
    compile 'com.netflix.rxjava:rxjava-async-util:0.17.5'
}
```

Comment: You can now use `Observable.fromCallable` or `Completable.fromAction` instead. Besides, you shouldn't import com.netflix.rxjava, it is a very old namespace, io.reactivex is the current one.